# Referencing outlets now showing my custom view (IBOutlet)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4.5

I'm trying to do a simple task and I don't know what I'm missing. I just want to link a referencing outlet using the IBOutlet that I've customized to the View Controller. But when I try to do the link, my custom `viewLabel` does not appear.
Here it is some images:

Code: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2GIL.jpg

Label class: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5BZfs.jpg

Link without viewLabel:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vet5P.jpg

Any help?

Thanks!

Comment: i havent ever seen anyone post an image of 2 lines of code before

Comment: Just to show that it's there...

Comment: aren't outlets supposed to be strong on iOS?

Comment: @GradyPlayer I have an example here that it's working, for sure I missed something

Comment: I thought i would be able to infer the question from the links... but i can't what isn't showing up? your custom subclass? or the outlet in interface builder?

Comment: @GradyPlayer the outlet in interface builder

Comment: well a couple of things could be happening, have you A) saved the Header file. B) defined that property in the header rather than a .m?

Comment: @GradyPlayer yes for both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its hard to understand your question correctly, but my guess would be you didn't set the viewcontroller's class to your custom viewcontroller subclass..... You do that in the class inspector pane.

Comment: Thanks! I re-checked and one was missing

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem.  Luckily, it was just a simple tutorial example.  I know I did everything right!  But I finally scrapped the entire, small project and recreated it from scratch and it worked.  Ctrl-Drag from the Reference link to the View Controller listed the @IBOutlet variables.